# Javascript regular expression adjustment

Tags: javascript, regex, mootools

Using mootools I have a regex like this:

```
new RegExp('^([^\\D'+ separator +']+)(\\d{2})');
```

In a string it inserts the char defined in separator after every 2 characters. I want it to insert only for the last two.

Example:

```
 String     Result
 123456     12.34.56  // what it does now
 123456     1234.56   // what it should do
```

I don't have much experience with regex so any help or link to a decent tutorial is appreciated.

Comment: What if the string is just two digits long? Should it still add the period?

Comment: (premising that doing this with a regexp is far from the optimum) try adding a final `$`: `new RegExp('([^\\D'+ separator +']+)(\\d{2})$');`

Comment: Add more examples. When you think of example, you can think of corner cases that you may want to handle differently.

Comment: I edited my answer, I thought you want the . after the first two instead of the last two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex for this:

```
var str = "123456".split('').reverse().join('');
var x = str.substring(0,2) + '.' + str.substring(2);
var final = x.split('').reverse().join('');

console.log(final);
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CTnV8/1/)

Of course you can check if the string length is bigger than 2

```
if (str.length > 2)
    // ...
```

---

Or use string `slice` function:

```
str ="123456";
str.slice(0, -2) + "." + str.slice(-2);
```

**How does it work?**
I'll break it into pieces:

```
// Start at the beginning of the string grab all the chars 
// and stop two chars before the end of the string
str.slice(0, -2)

// Start at two chars before the end of the string, take all the chars until  
// the  end of the string.
str.slice(-2);
```

Comment: You can substring with negative number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Comment: Thx. Simplicity wins :-) I was using a library (also used for masking other fields somewhere else) but in this case simple = better.

Comment: str = str.substr(0, (str.length-2)) + ',' + str.substr(-2); works more elegant but thanks for steering me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your string only consists of digits, isn't this the same as divide by 100?

```
'' + str / 100
```

It might depend on locale though ;-)

I can improve this answer if you have more edge cases I can work with.

---

If you absolutely must just regular expressions, you could always use this:

```
'123456'.replace(/(.)(\d{2})$/, function($0, $1, $2) { 
    return $1 + '.' + $2; 
});
```

This would protect you against strings that would otherwise result in `NaN`, such as `'foo'`.

Comment: why `'' + str` instead of `parseInt(str)` ?

Comment: @poncha I assumed he wants a string as the result

Comment: Indeed it depends on locale. Use case is a financial form: values are stored as cents (eg 1050 for EUR 10,50) but users want to see EUR 10,50. A few calculations are done with the values. Using float gives odd results (EUR 10,499999999999) etc. Wit the mask I can replace the comma, then parse to int.

Comment: Probably yes :-) But opted for the substr solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the string always has more than 2 characters:

```
str.slice(0, -2) + "." + str.slice(-2)
```

Reference to [String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).